# Identify external and internal hard drive in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am working now to differentiate between external and internal drives. I've used `Get-Drive`, `Get-Disk`, `Get-PhysicalDisk`, `Get-CimInstance Win32_LogicalDisk`, but they are all almost the same. I can't really figure out, what the difference between them is, if I try to identify my external drive? Thanks

Comment: Maybe `(Get-PhysicalDisk).PhysicalLocation` will have something you can use?

Comment: the `Get-PhysicalDisk` output has a `.BusType` property. for all my internal drives, that shows `ATA` [they are SATA]. i suspect a USB connection would show that, but i have none to test with.

Answer (score 1):

`Get-PhysicalDisk` is the one I prefer. Check out the properties `FriendlyName`, `Model`, and/or `MediaType` like so, and see if one of the model names matches what's on your external hard drive. I also convert the disk space from bytes to GB to make it easier to tell the difference between drives:

```
Get-PhysicalDisk | 
  Select DeviceID,MediaType,
    @{l='Size (GB)';e={[math]::Round($_.Size / 1GB)}},
    FriendlyName,Model 

DeviceID     : 0
MediaType    : SSD
Size (GB)    : 119
FriendlyName : SAMSUNG MZFLV128HCGR-000MV
Model        : SAMSUNG MZFLV128HCGR-000MV
```

Another way to check is through WMI via `Get-CimInstance win32_diskdrive` like this:

```
Get-CimInstance win32_diskdrive | 
  Select Index,InterfaceType,Manufacturer,MediaType,Model,
    @{l='Size (GB)';e={[math]::Round($_.Size / 1GB)}}

Index         : 0
InterfaceType : SCSI
Manufacturer  : (Standard disk drives)
MediaType     : Fixed hard disk media
Model         : SAMSUNG MZFLV128HCGR-000MV
Size (GB)     : 119
```

Even better, hard drives connected via USB will usually have an `InterfaceType` of `USB`, but you'll have to try it out to see.